# Big-O of Copying Elements in a Dynamic Array

Tags: algorithm, big-o

So I would like to ask about the asymptotic growth of copying elements in a dynamic array algorithm.

In the dynamic array algorithm, the array is doubled in size every time that is it full and a new element is supposed to be added. When the array is full, it contains N/2 elements, and after it is doubled, the size of the new array is 2N. The next element is then inserted at after the copied objects/values.

I believed that the Big-O for the number of elements copied would be O(N/2), but would I also have to account for the times that the array has been doubled?

Just to be very clear, this is a problem that my instructor has assigned, and I have been thinking about it, but I'm currently unsure about if/how to account for the number of times the array has been doubled, given only a size N array.

Comment: When the array is full, it contains N/2 elements, and then it is doubled, and the result is an array of size 2N... I think you misread the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> I believed that the Big-Oh for the number of elements copied would be O(N/2), but would I also have to account for the times that the array has been doubled?

What you are looking for might be the distinction between the per-operation complexity and the [amortized complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).

In particular, the worst-time complexity of an insertion in a dynamic array is indeed `O(N)`, but the amortized complexity is `O(1)` (since for `N` insertions at most `2*N` elements are copied).

Comment: But isn't that amortized complexity only for the amount of time it takes for an insertion? I'm looking specifically for the big-O of the number of elements that have been copied as the array has grown to size N. Forgive me if I did not understand your answer correctly.

Comment: @Ash Maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought you needed to calculate the complexity (in time or in the number of elements copied) of a single operation, and also to take into account the fact that most operations do not involve copying.

Comment: @Ash If you need the time complexity of filling an array of size `N` with insertions, it is also `O(N)`. It can be calculated as the sum of a geometric progression: `N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... ≈ N`.

Comment: Yep, okay so that makes more sense. Sorry, I don't think I phrased my question correctly, but the way you answered it makes complete sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

let N be the number of elements to be appended to the array. If the array starts empty with a size of zero, for which elements does the array need to be resize? assuming it starts with capacity 1:

```
    size | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 16 17 
 capacity| 0 1 2 4   8      16 ... 32
```

so, the array is resized a total of log(N)+1 times. The total number of element copied though is:

```
       size | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 16 17 
    capacity| 0 1 2 4   8      16 ... 32
total copied| 0 0 1 3   7      15 ... 31 ...
```

So, the total number of copies is ~2*N which is O(N)

Note however that this is the case if you insert N elements one after the other in an originally empty growing array. This is why typical implementation allow you to specify an initial capacity, so if you have a decent guess on how many elements you will insert, you can start with a capacity != 0.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. The diagram is very helpful.